# How can I test a DoS attack against snort?

Tags: ids, denial-of-service, snort

I need to set up an scenario where an attacker DoS attacks port 80 of an server while snort and others users try to connect to port 80 at the same time.
Something like this:

- 1000 connections to port 80
- 800 analyzed by Snort
- 750 detected like DoS attack by Snort

How can I get these values? What tools I need besides snort?

Comment: There are many load-testing utilities out there. A nice one that acts as a tool and a library is <a href="https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta">Vegeta</a>. I have had a lot of fun using it and it offers very detailed results.

Comment: Welcome to this Q&A site. This answer is very short. I recommend that you provide some more information to this answer. What is Vegeta, and what does it do?

Answer (score 1):

There are many cheap stress-testing services that offer a variety of attack vectors to attack with.

Once you purchase a membership, you simply login to their website and input your site's URL/IP address and chose an attack method (UDP, SYN, HTTP, ect)

Note that these services are usually illegally ran by teenagers trying to make a couple bucks.

Nonetheless, these services are great for testing your website with different attack methods and good for testing the strength of your DDOS protection/firewall.